# Symfony Swiftmailer Gmail - Not working on remote server

Tags: symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

I have configured symfony to send emails using gmail:

```
// .env file
MAILER_URL=gmail://<email>:<password>@localhost?encryption=tls&auth_mode=oauth
```

When I run `./bin/console swiftmailer:email:send` on my local dev machine the email is sent out.

I have the same setting on a staging server and when I run `./bin/console swiftmailer:email:send` on this machine I get an error

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "username" using 1 possible authenticators

I have turned on access for less secure apps in gmail.

I don't understand why it would authenticate on my local machine and not the staging server.

Comment: are you using dev mode in remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to the following link:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and then click the button.

I found this link by digging around on SO. Unfortunately, it was not documented or mentioned by google, but it solved my issue.